# Sending variables as body of mailto on asp:button

Tags: html, asp.net, mailto

I have a website which I want users to be able to share a link via email. This particular page is the mobile version.

I have an asp:button using mailto and I need to pass variables from the page to build the URL in the email body.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnEmail" runat="server" Width="70%"  Text="Share Property" PostBackUrl='<%#"mailto:?subject=Check out this property at xxx - " & DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.PropertyName") & "body=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.PropertyID")%>'/>
```

The mailto is working and the subject is populating but the mail body seems to contain the viewstate of the page:

```
__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKMTM4ODYwNDQ2Mg9kFgJmD2QWAgIDD2QWAmYPZBYCAgEPFgIeC18hSXRlbUNvdW50AgEWAmYPZBYKAgEPFgIeCWlubmVyaHRtbAXCAzx1bCBjbGFzcz0nc2xpZGVzJz48bGk%2BPGltZyBzcmM9Jy4uL2Z0cC9wQlJBTkNIX1AxMzQxLmpwZycgLz48L2xpPjxsaT48aW1nIHNyYz0nLi4vZnRwLzYtQlJBTkNIX1AxMzQxLmpwZycgLz48L2xpPjxsaT48aW1nIHNyYz0nLi4vZnRwLzctQlJBTkNIX1AxMzQxLmpwZycgLz48L2xpPjxsaT48aW1nIHNyYz0nLi4vZnRwLzgtQlJBTkNIX1AxMzQxLmpwZycgLz48L2xpPjxsaT48aW1nIHNyYz0nLi4vZnRwL2FCUkFOQ0hfUDEzNDEuanBnJyAvPjwvbGk%2BPGxpPjxpbWcgc3JjPScuLi9mdHAvYkJSQU5DSF9QMTM0MS5qcGcnIC8%2BPC9saT48bGk%2BPGltZyBzcmM9Jy4uL2Z0cC9jQlJBTkNIX1AxMzQxLmpwZycgLz48L2xpPjxsaT48aW1nIHNyYz0nLi4vZnRwL2RCUkFOQ0hfUDEzNDEuanBnJyAvPjwvbGk%2BPGxpPjxpbWcgc3JjPScuLi9mdHAvZUJSQU5DSF9QMTM0MS5qcGcnIC8%2BPC9saT48L3VsPmQCAg8VBRpSZWR3b29kIENsb3NlLCBTb3V0aCBPeGhleQM2NzUDUENNBVAxMzQxnwFPbmUgYmVkcm9vbSB0b3AgZmxvb3IgZmxhdCB3aXRoIGZpdHRlZCBiYXRocm9vbSwgZml0dGVkIGtpdGNoZW4gd2l0aCB3YXNoaW5nIG1hY2hpbmUsIGZyaWRnZSwgY29va2VyIGFuZCBtaWNyb3dhdmUuICBBdmFpbGFibGUgbm93IGZ1cm5pc2hlZC4gIEVuZXJneSBSYXRpbmcgRS5kAgMPDxYCHgtQb3N0QmFja1VybAUlaHR0cDovL21hcHMuYXBwbGUuY29tL21hcHM%2FcT1XRDE5IDZTRWRkAgUPDxYCHwIFHFJlcXVlc3RWaWV3aW5nLmFzcHg%2FSUQ9UDEzNDFkZAIHDw8WAh8CBWNtYWlsdG86P3N1YmplY3Q9Q2hlY2sgb3V0IHRoaXMgcHJvcGVydHkgYXQgSm9obiBXaGl0ZW1hbiAtIFJlZHdvb2QgQ2xvc2UsIFNvdXRoIE94aGV5Ym9keT10ZXN0UDEzNDFkZGQlH8aveHqM96GJK6rcUKFtYormuw%3D%3D&__PREVIOUSPAGE=jXBhZExXbPAJGCoKEgVxPvQrYIK2wX4xu1Pu8m0He281&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWBQLLnPHNBQKLm%2B%2BxDQKTlZGGAQKbi8jQCALB16nOAksIgJxExXvoFLdOr%2FT%2F56iiVmxW&ctl00%24MainContent%24myDataRepeater%24ctl00%24btnEmail=Share+Property
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Button` wants to do a postback, which contains all form fields.

You can also use a `<a href="mailto:...">` to initiate an e-mail from the user's mail program. You don't need the `runat=server` here.

You can style that link to look like a button.

Comment: Ah thank you, that makes perfect sense. Could I use a linkbutton?

Comment: @Helen - A linkbutton would also do a postback. If you don't need that, why complicate things? The HTML still would be a `<a href=..>`

Comment: Just thinking from an ease of styling point of view but that's just me being lazy ;-)    The a href worked like a dream.